# Python: How do i pull out items from an array in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have two arrays, and one of them is an array containing arrays.

```
wordsEn = ["why", "because", "go"] 
wordsDe = [["warum"], ["weil", "da"], ["los", "gehen"]]
```

my code is

```
step = 0
size = 3
while step < size:
    word = input("Enter name of word: ")
    print("your word was " + word)
    if word in wordsEn:
       pos = wordsEn.index(word)
       print(wordsDe[pos])
       step = step + 1
    else:
        print("word not found.")
```

if i ask it print `wordsDe[1]` it prints `['weil', 'da']`

How do I make it print it as a list like

`weil
 da`

Comment: You can also access the inner array by indexing eg. wordsDe[1][0] should print 'weil'. You can keep doing this as long as the index is valid, eg. wordsDe[1][0][0] should print 'w'.

Comment: `print(*wordsDe[1],sep='\n')`

Comment: I don't understand how that piece of code is relevant to your question?

Answer (score 0):

wordsDe is a list and the 3 objects in the list are ["warum"], ["weil", "da"], and  ["los", "gehen"].

Calling wordsDe[1] will give you the second object in the list ... ["weil", "da"]

If you want to print it

```
weil
da
```

you must call wordsDe[1][0] and then wordsDe[1][1]

Comment: Whoops, fixed it.

Comment: *you must call wordsDe[1][0] and then wordsDe[1][1]* - not very accurate... Check out the other answers

Answer (score 0):

```
step = 0
size = 3
while step < size:
    word = input("Enter name of word: ")
    print("your word was " + word)
    if word in wordsEn:
       pos = wordsEn.index(word)
       for i in range(len(wordsDe[pos])):
          print(wordsDe[pos][i])
       step = step + 1
    else:
       print("word not found.")

Enter name of word: because
your word was because
weil
da
Enter name of word: go
your word was go
los
gehen
Enter name of word: why
your word was why
warum
```

For array of arrays we should use two dimensions to access individual elements.

Comment: Your `for` loop will be much more simple if you just did `for word in wordsDe[pos]: print(word)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested loops for this.
**Use two loops and a separator argument in print function.**
*The separator is not necessary here*

```
step = 0
size = 3
while step < size:

    word = input("Enter name of word: ")
    print("your word was " + word)
    if word in wordsEn:
        pos = wordsEn.index(word)

        for item in wordsDe[pos]:
            print(item,sep="\n")

        step = step + 1
    else:
        print("word not found.")
```

Comment: I think you meant the `end` argument rather than `sep`, which is the default anyway and is not necessary. `sep` is only relevant when you pass multiple arguments

Answer (score 0):

You can cycle wordsDe[pos] and simply print contents one by one.

```
step = 0
size = 3
while step < size:
    word = input("Enter name of word: ")
    print("your word was " + word)
    if word in wordsEn:
       pos = wordsEn.index(word)
       for data in wordsDe[pos]:
           print (data)
       step = step + 1
    else:
        print("word not found.")
```

Answer (score 0):

As your list is nested, means lists containing lists. You have to specify the output format for such lists according to your desired output.

For given situation you can use something list this:

```py
print(*wordsDe[1], sep='\n') # First unpacks all items in the list using '*', 
                             # then tells 'print()' to separate each item using '\n'
```

Answer (score -2):

Change list's items to string:

```
wordsEn = ["why", "because", "go"] 
wordsDe = [["warum"], ["weil", "da"], ["los", "gehen"]]

step = 0 ;size = 3 
while step < size: 
    word = input("Enter name of word: ") 
    print("your word was " + word) 
    if word in wordsEn: 
        pos = wordsEn.index(word) 
        w=''
        for wd in wordsDe[pos]:
            w+=wd+' '
        print(w)
        step = step + 1 
    else: 
        print("word not found.")
```

Comment: That prints the list in one line - not what is asked for. And would anyway be achieved easier by a simple `print(*wordsDe[ps])`